# How to find approximately close values in different number of rows from two dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frame one with 24 row*2 columns and another with 258 row*2 columns. The columns are similar, I am interested in one column and want to find the values in two data frame that are approximately close to each other?

I am trying to simulate a spectrum and compare with an experiment.

```
df_exp <- data.frame("Name"=c(exp,Int), "exp" = c(x1, x2, x3, ...,x258),"int"= c(y1,y2,y3,...,y258))

df_sim <- data.frame("Name"=c(sim,Int), "sim" = c(x1, x2, x3, ...,x24),"int" = c(y1,y2,y3,...,y24))
```

Initial values (`exp` column from `df_exp` and `sim` column from `df_sim`):

```
exp             sim     
206.0396    182.0812        
207.1782    229.1183        
229.0776    246.1448        
232.1367    302.1135        
241.1050    319.1401        
246.1691    357.1769        
250.0235    374.2034
...             ...
```

I tried this r code

```
match(df_exp$exp[1:258], df_sim$sim[1:24], nomatch = 0)
```

This code gives me all zero values because there is no exact match. The numbers always vary in decimal places. I tried to round the numbers to zero decimal places, and find values that are close. But that is not my intent. I want to find `df_exp(229.0776,246.1691,...)` and `df_sim(229.1183, 246.1448,...)` and make a new data frame with all those approximately close values. Can you please suggest some help?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a similarity cutoff and loop over them:

```
### define your cutoff for similarity
cutoff <- 0.01
### initialize vectors to store the similar values
similar_sim <- vector(); similar_exp <- vector();
### open loop over both DF values
for (sim_value in df_sim$sim) {
  for (exp_value in df_exp$exp) {
    ### if similar (< cutoff) append values to vectors
    if ( abs(sim_value - exp_value) < cutoff ) {
      similar_sim <- append(similar_sim, sim_value)
      expilar_exp <- append(expilar_exp, exp_value)
    }
  }
}
### recreate a DF with the similar values
similar_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(similar_sim, similar_exp))
```

if you want to save every values of one similar to the value of the other as it sounds. Otherwise you can skip a loop and use range selection, e.g:

```
x[ x < x+cutoff & x > x-cutoff ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I find solution from previous post and tried that worked for me. a=df$mz_sim
b=df$mz_exp
cuts <- c(-Inf, b[-1]-diff(b)/2, Inf)
cuttoff_match <- data.frame(cut(a, breaks=cuts, labels=b))
cuttoff_match